# Install Bundler failed in Ruby Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a very old project I'm giving support. I'm using docker to make my builds and everything was working until this last one try.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.1

# Install apt based dependencies required to run Rails as 
# well as RubyGems. As the Ruby image itself is based on a 
# Debian image, we use apt-get to install those.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    git \
    ghostscript \
    libgs-dev \
    build-essential \ 
    libmysqlclient-dev \
    locales \
    nodejs

# Use en_US.UTF-8 as our locale
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8 
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en 
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# Configure the main working directory. This is the base 
# directory used in any further RUN, COPY, and ENTRYPOINT 
# commands.
RUN mkdir -p /app 
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gemfile as well as the Gemfile.lock and install 
# the RubyGems. This is a separate step so the dependencies 
# will be cached unless changes to one of those two files 
# are made.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./ 
COPY vendor/oohlalog_gem ./vendor/oohlalog_gem
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install

# Copy the main application.
COPY . ./

# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it 
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure an entry point, so we don't need to specify 
# "bundle exec" for each of our commands.
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also 
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by 
# default.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

When I try to run:

```
docker build . -t my_image
```

I'm getting:

> Step 11 : RUN gem install bundler && bundle install
>   ---> Running in 7f8e7442b423 ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
>   bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.

I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of a release of a new Bundler version 2.0.0 that happened on January 03, 2019. According to GitHub [issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6865) this is a desired behaviour.

As this is an old and not maintained anymore project the best option for you would be using older bundler.

You can modify the line from your Dockerfile:

```
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install
```

to the following:

```
RUN gem install bundler -v '$OLD_BUNDLER_VERSION' && bundle install
```

where $OLD_BUNDLER_VERSION should be set to last known working version, i.e. 1.16.1

Answer (score 0):

Try a newer version of ruby image as your base. You are using 2.1 ( `FROM ruby:2.1` ) but you need ruby version 2.3.0

Comment: Yes. I already did that. But I got an error because of  libmysqlclient-dev \

Its a 10 yrs old project, and I dont know what this lib do. 

Bundler was created only at ruby 2.3?

Comment: I think so. I am not familiar with Ruby but it seems that you may need 2.3.1 for bundler. Or you can dig around bundler and see if any of its previous versions are compatible with 2.1 and you can try using that version explicitly. I doubt it though.

Also that lib looks like a mysql client. Unless it is custom, you can get a newer version. But that might break other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My way is to use the correct bundler version and run it like this:

```
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.2.26
RUN gem update --system \
    && gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION \
    && bundle install -j 4
```